# filter show not the correct list after he did the filtering

Tags: java, android, filter

I have edited my Adapter class and extended the filterable class. My search functionality works but i am unable to get the currect list.

here is my adapter class:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
Context context;
private List<Student> studentList;
private List<Student> orginStudentList;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,List<Student> studentList)
{
    this.studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.studentList = studentList;
    this.orginStudentList = studentList;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(nameFilter == null)
        nameFilter = new NameFilter();
    return nameFilter;
}
public void resetData() {
    studentList = orginStudentList;
}
private class NameFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        // We implement here the filter logic
        if ((constraint == null) || (constraint.length() == 0)) {
            // No filter implemented we return all the list
            results.values = orginStudentList;
            results.count = orginStudentList.size();
        }else if (Character.isDigit(constraint.charAt(constraint.length()-1))){
            results.values = studentList;
            results.count = studentList.size();
        }
        else {
            // We perform filtering operation
            List<Student> nStudentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
            for (Student stu : orginStudentList) {
                String name = stu.getName();
                if (name.contains(constraint))
                    nStudentList.add(stu);
            }
            results.values = nStudentList;
            results.count = nStudentList.size();
        }
        return results;
    }
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        studentList = (List<Student>)results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}
I do check if the results are zero or null and if so to return the currect list? What am I missing?

Comment: any error logged in debug console ?

Comment: please add your FilterResults class code

Comment: this the code of the FilterResults class ....

Comment: and no debug error

Answer (score 0):

add notifyDataSetChanged(); inside adapter

Comment: isn't work. becuse when i type latter that dont contain is return good. but when i write letter that the second item contain the list return without the this item

Comment: Use debugger .. Mark where data retrieve and print.. It will help you what exact problem

Comment: i use... he send all good and he steal print wrong, he print on Looper then i dont find exactly where this print

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void filter(String text) {
        List<Model> filterdNames = new ArrayList<>();


        for (Model s : Models) {

            if (s.getName().contains(text)) {

                filterdNames.add(s);
            }
        }

        //calling a method of the adapter class and passing the filtered list
        recyclerAdapter.filterList(filterdNames);
    }
```